# How to destroy applicationOn events for Nativescript lifecycles in Angular

Tags: angular, nativescript

In my Nativescript + Angular phone app, I have managed to listen to suspend and resume events by placing them into the constructor as follows:

```js
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor(private router: RouterExtensions,
            private tokenService: TokenStoreService) {

        applicationOn(suspendEvent, (args: ApplicationEventData) => {
            tokenService.bioScanSetAuthenticated(false);
            tokenService.setLastRoute(this.router.router.url);
        });

        applicationOn(resumeEvent, (args: ApplicationEventData) => {
            if (this.tokenService.bioScanIsAuthenticated()) {
                return;
            }
            this.router.navigate(['/login'], { animated: false, clearHistory: true });
        });
    }
}
```

This works great and the app behaves as expected, however when logging comments to the console output from within these `applicationOn` methods I notice that each time an additional comment is being made whenever the app is suspended and resumed. This indicates that the `applicationOn` events are being recreated each time the class is loaded rather than being destroyed.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: unless youre doing parent/child navigation or are telling the page to remain, the page/class will be destroyed when you navigate away

Comment: The HomeComponent is in a child module `HomeModule` which is a child to `AppModule`. Is that the issue?

Comment: no, thats not parent/child. parent/child is how the routes relate to each other

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend handling global events (like `applicationOn`) within a service with root scope which would probably be initialised only once. This service may host a Subject / Observable which would emit upon resume / suspend events.

But if you like a hot fix for your current problem, remove the event listeners in the destroy life cycle callback.

```
import { applicationOff as off } from from "tns-core-modules/application";

....

ngOnDestroy() {
    // This will remove all active event listeners at once, 
    // If you want to remove one particular listener, you will have to pass the function reference as second parameter
    applicationOff(suspendEvent);
    applicationOff(resumeEvent);
}
```